# Nginx: WordPress Rewrites not Working unless I do bad things

Tags: wordpress, nginx, url-rewriting

I just recently migrated from Apache to Nginx and I am running into a brick wall with Wordpress and Nginx. For the time being I am running a more simple Nginx conf so you can more easily see what is going on without having to look at 50 more lines which are fine.

```html
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     servername.com
    root            /home/sname/www;

    # IF I DON'T DO THIS ALL PAGES APART FROM THE HOMEPAGE DON'T APPEAR!
    # Further to this, I use a custom permalink structure %post_name%.
    # When turned off the pages work but I can't use custom permalink structure
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
    }

    # PHP Handler
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I have all the usuals in the HTTP block:

```html
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    index   index.php index.html index.htm;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Why can't I just live with this? Well here is a sitewide example. (subbed in sitename! due to bad URLS and link limit)

http://www.pro-tradesouthwales.co.uk/services/damp-proofing/ <-- The page I want to serve 
sitename!/services/damp-proofing <--- Doesn't display 404 (All below display a blank page) 
sitename!/services/damp-proofing/index.php <--- Doesn't display 404 or Redirect 
sitename!/services/damp-proofing/index.php/ <--- OK this is bad!

sitename!/services/damp-proofing/index.php/index.php <--- O GOD!

Any and all helps appreciated. I have tried so many different setups and been trying to get this to work for several days. Please don't patronise me by saying something like read a guide, I ate the god damn nginx dictionary still to no avail :)

Thanks guys!

Comment: What happens if you remove the try_files $uri =404; line in the PHP handler? Also, do you have a general location / block anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working to an extent. Turns out WordPress just has issues but this is as far as I know the most "correct" way to setup a WordPress website :)

Hope it helps others too. Remember things change depending on your server and it's unique setup. So your PHP setup may be different. For example php-fpm directory doesn't always exist and is sometimes created as php5-fpm too. If in doubt use a shell (connect to your server via SSH using putty or something similar) AND go find php-fpm.sock.

AKA: 
cd /etc/
dir -a 
---- SHOWS LIST OF FILES ----
...
etc

```html
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.pro-tradesouthwales.co.uk;
        root         /home/protrade/www;

        rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
        
        # START: Solution
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
        # END: Solution

        location ~ /\. {
                deny all;
        }

        location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
                deny all;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }

        location ~* \.()$ {
               log_not_found off;
               expires max;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```